# Adding images to a website in CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I'm new to HTML/CSS and am trying to change an image on the website I am working on. There's an image saved to the website (at foo.com/bar, the CSS has it set at /bar), and I don't know how to upload a picture from there. Sorry this is such a basic question but I don't know much at all about CSS/HTML

EDIT:
My bad for not explaining myself well enough, I was in a hurry to finish yesterday.

We have the image but it's not uploaded to the website. The original image we're trying to replace is uploaded to foo.com/image/bar.jpg, but it was uploaded there before I started working this job and I don't know how to replace it or put another image in its place in the CSS. Should I just change the CSS to look at the file's location on the computer, like

```
<img src = "C:foo/bar.jpg">
```

Comment: Please be more specific and provide more details. What do you mean by "upload a picture from there"?

Comment: are you trying to embed the image in your website? is it even live? do you have code?

Comment: Please add code you tried, what happens, and what you want to happen. Without the above, we cannot help, only take ugly guesses.

Comment: Updated the post, hopefully that makes thing a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Basic html for embedding an image

```
<img src="http://www.foo.com/folder/image.jpg" alt="My image" height="100" width="100">
```

or you can set h/w to auto or specify your own

if you are setting it as a [background image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) in your css you can do

```
background-image: url("http://www.foo.com/folder/image.jpg");
```

within the div/body css

Comment: I edited the post, hopefully that makes thing a bit more clear. I'm not trying to upload a picture from an existing folder on the website, I'm trying to replace an image in that folder with another one.

Comment: @Sig you can't point to a local file on your desktop from your website, it needs to be uploaded before you can use the image